# Could you help me to extract level and other info from this clash of clans account?

Tags: clash-of-clans

[image]

Regarding to the image above, I want to answer the questions below like what are the levels. I tried to answer some but I'm not sure if they are true. I'm learning and appreciate your help.

- Account Level:    115 ???
- Town Hall Level:  Level 10????
- Wall Levels:  Level 7????
- Max Troops:   ??????
- Max Gold Storage: 8 500 000????
- Max Elixir Storage:   8 500 000????
- Max Dark Elixir Storage:   200 000????
- Trophies Earned:  ????????
- Trophy League:     2715 Master????
- Barbarian King Level:
- Archer Queen Level:
- Grand Warden Level:
- Maxed Troops or Troop Levels:
- Building and Defense Levels:

Comment: Where'd you get the picture? That'd be the best place to find this, I bet.

Comment: I got the image from a friend. He's pro at it. But I don't understand his levels.

Comment: Quite a nice question from a new user.

Comment: Looking for a nice answer as well! I can't find a good website which teaches these stuff.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the King is level 14, and he doesn't have a Grand Warden as he's a TH 10.

Comment: ُThanks Jacky. How do you the king level? And do you about other levels?! any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here is what I see:**

- Username:                     siroos2
- Account Level:                115
- Town Hall Level:              Level 10
- Wall Levels:                  Level 7
- Max Troops:                   Doubtful.
- Max Gold Storage:             8500000
- Max Elixir Storage:           8500000
- Max Dark Elixir Storage:      200000
- Gems:                         1356
- Trophies Earned:              2715
- Trophy League:                Master
- Barbarian King Level:         14
- Archer Queen Level:           13 going on 14 (has a 6 day upgrade time)
- Grand Warden Level:           N/A (TH 11)
- Maxed Troops or Troop Levels: I think I see lv 6 Wizards, Barbs and Archers
- Building and Defense Levels:

**Defenses:**

> Archer Towers: 10 + 11,
>   Wizard Towers: 8,
>   Mortars: 7,
>   Cannons: 11,
>   Air Defense: 6,
>   Air Sweepers: 4?,
>   Xbows: 3?,
>   Inferno Towers: 1 + 2,
>   Teslas: 4?

**Buildings:**

> Barracks: 10 + 9,
>   Dark Barracks: 5,
>   Army Camps: 8,
>   Collectors: 12,
>   Storages: 11,
>   Laboratory: 8,
>   Spell Factory: 5,
>   Dark Spell Factory: 3, 
>   Clan Castle: 5,
>   Total Builders: 4/5,

So he has all troops except the lava hound, and all spells.
Over all this base is quite rushed.

**Note:** ? means I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @Moh no problem, just added some more stuff

Comment: @Moh if that answers your question remember to mark it as complete!

Comment: Done! Sry, it was my first time. @Daedric

Comment: If you expand the image and zoom in, you can clearly see that the Barbarian King is level 14.

Comment: @Ellesedil lol, I don't know how I missed that.